# How to search logs between dates using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to search through some logs while grepping for a specific line. How can I reduce the following logs even further by date and time? For example all lines between 2018/02/27 13:10:31 to 2018/02/27 13:17:34. I've tried using sed but I can't get it to work correctly on either date columns.

```
grep "Eps=" file.log

INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:02:27 | [Tue Feb 27 13:02:27 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5618.819672131148, Evts=2077762260}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:03:27 | [Tue Feb 27 13:03:27 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5288.8, Evts=2078079588}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:04:27 | [Tue Feb 27 13:04:27 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5176.633333333333, Evts=2078390186}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:05:28 | [Tue Feb 27 13:05:28 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5031.633333333333, Evts=2078692084}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:06:28 | [Tue Feb 27 13:06:28 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5047.433333333333, Evts=2078994930}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:07:30 | [Tue Feb 27 13:07:29 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5314.183333333333, Evts=2079313781}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:08:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:08:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5182.934426229508, Evts=2079629940}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:09:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:09:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5143.459016393443, Evts=2079943691}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:10:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:10:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5519.266666666666, Evts=2080274847}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:11:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:11:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5342.8, Evts=2080595415}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:12:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:12:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5230.183333333333, Evts=2080909226}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:13:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:13:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=4975.533333333334, Evts=2081207758}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:14:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:14:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5225.283333333334, Evts=2081521275}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:15:33 | [Tue Feb 27 13:15:33 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5261.766666666666, Evts=2081836981}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:16:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:16:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5257.688524590164, Evts=2082157700}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:17:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:17:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5634.133333333333, Evts=2082495748}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:18:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:18:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5490.5, Evts=2082825178}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:19:35 | [Tue Feb 27 13:19:35 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5351.05, Evts=2083146241}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:20:37 | [Tue Feb 27 13:20:37 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5022.983606557377, Evts=2083452643}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:21:37 | [Tue Feb 27 13:21:37 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5302.196721311476, Evts=2083776077}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:22:37 | [Tue Feb 27 13:22:37 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5096.2, Evts=2084081849}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:23:37 | [Tue Feb 27 13:23:37 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5074.45, Evts=2084386316}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:24:38 | [Tue Feb 27 13:24:38 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5264.566666666667, Evts=2084702190}
```

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Tools like sed or grep operate on strings, even when you can do really sophisticated stuff using regular expressions.
But these tools lack the ability to do something like "range queries" for things like date.

You might find various solutions to this questions, mine would include a small python snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys
from datetime import datetime
begin = datetime(2018,2,27,13,10,31) 
end = datetime(2018,2,27,13,47,34)
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    if begin <= datetime.strptime(line.split('|')[2].strip(),'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') <= end:
        print(line[:-1])
```

That snipped saved as filter.py and made executable (e.g. chmod +x) could then be called like this:

```
grep "Eps=" file.log | filter.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that will do the job in shell but as [Stefan Sonnenberg-Carstens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9208325/stefan-sonnenberg-carstens) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017825/3691891) consider using `Python` for that job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

from=$(grep '2018/02/27 13:10:31' -n file.log | cut -d: -f1)
to=$(grep '2018/02/27 13:17:34' -n file.log | cut -d: -f1)
head -$to file.log  | tail +$from
```

Output:

```
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:10:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:10:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5519.266666666666, Evts=2080274847}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:11:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:11:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5342.8, Evts=2080595415}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:12:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:12:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5230.183333333333, Evts=2080909226}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:13:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:13:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=4975.533333333334, Evts=2081207758}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:14:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:14:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5225.283333333334, Evts=2081521275}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:15:33 | [Tue Feb 27 13:15:33 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5261.766666666666, Evts=2081836981}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:16:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:16:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5257.688524590164, Evts=2082157700}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:17:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:17:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5634.133333333333, Evts=2082495748}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) *one-liner* - try to find a more concise and clear way :)

```
perl -ne 'print if m|2018/02/27 13:10:31| .. m|2018/02/27 13:17:34|' file
```

### Output :

```
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:10:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:10:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5519.266666666666, Evts=2080274847}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:11:31 | [Tue Feb 27 13:11:31 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5342.8, Evts=2080595415}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:12:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:12:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5230.183333333333, Evts=2080909226}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:13:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:13:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=4975.533333333334, Evts=2081207758}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:14:32 | [Tue Feb 27 13:14:32 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5225.283333333334, Evts=2081521275}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:15:33 | [Tue Feb 27 13:15:33 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5261.766666666666, Evts=2081836981}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:16:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:16:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5257.688524590164, Evts=2082157700}
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2018/02/27 13:17:34 | [Tue Feb 27 13:17:34 EST 2018] [INFO ] {Eps=5634.133333333333, Evts=2082495748}
```